# Umbraco 7: Change URLs to uppercase / lowercase

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

How can I change all URLs to uppercase / lowercase, or change the default naming convention?

Eg. from:

```
http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/
```

to:

```
http://our.umbraco.org/Projects/Backoffice-Extensions/
```

Comment: why do you need it to be in capital leters?

Comment: because the original version of the site I'm working on has all the url's uppercase, this is for google search engine cache pages, do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Alex our example does not convert to upper case but just capitalize the first letter. If that is what are ou trying to achieve you want this CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(text); then you need to apply.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is exactly what is stated in the question. You are right `capitalize the first letter`

Answer (score 2):

This is not so hard if you know how to program C#.

You basically need to write your own [UrlSegmentProvider (see documentation)](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/Request-Pipeline/outbound-pipeline).

```
public class UppercaseUrlSegmentProvider: IUrlSegmentProvider
{ 
    private readonly IUrlSegmentProvider provider = new DefaultUrlSegmentProvider();
    public string GetUrlSegment(IContentBase content)
    {
        return this.GetUrlSegment(content, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
    public string GetUrlSegment(IContentBase content, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Maybe you don't want to do that for all contentTypes
        // if so, check on the contentType:  if (content.ContentTypeId != 1086)

        var segment = this.provider.GetUrlSegment(content);

        // for the sake of simplicity I have put everything in uppercase, 
        // you could of course implement something like this: 
        // http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Data-Types/CamelCase.htm    
        return segment.ToUpper().ToUrlSegment();
    }       
}
```

To activate your segment provider, you can use the ApplicationStarting method of the [ApplicationEventHandler](http://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Events/application-startup).

```
public class MySegmentEvents : ApplicationEventHandler
{
    protected override void ApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication,     ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        base.ApplicationStarting(umbracoApplication, applicationContext);
        // UrlSegmentProviderResolver.Current.Clear();
        UrlSegmentProviderResolver.Current.InsertType<UppercaseUrlSegmentProvider>(0);
    }
}
```

Attention, if you have implemented the code above, the existing nodes won't change automatically.  It's only after a "Save And Publish" that your URL of the particular node will have it's new "segment".

Comment: Thanks! I implemented this but the URI segments are the still lowercase. This is what I did: 1. Created in root project a folder called `UrlSegmentProvider`, inside this folder I created the provided classes `UppercaseUrlSegmentProvider`and `MySegmentEvents` and included required namespaces. 2. In BO I published Home and all its subpages and also republished entire site. What am I missing?

Comment: @alex how do you render the url to the page?

Comment: I have the `umbracoUrlName` property on all pages but not all have value set on them, does this influence with something? Can the `umbracoUrlName` values be programmatically set to uppercase for all pages?

Comment: if you mean `@Umbraco.NiceUrl(1071)`, this is how I render the url

Comment: @alex the code above WILL CHANGE the umbracoUrlName property on every publish.  But only for the current node.  You can control with the code above the "name" property for every node.